# Assured non-zero orthogonal projection of a vector

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

This question is related to the [Symmetrical and skew-symmetrical part of rotation matrix](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1853872/symmetrical-and-skew-symmetrical-part-of-rotation-matrix)

Let's suppose that we have orthogonal projection matrix $P$ onto subspace generated by a unit vector $v$.

**Questions:**

- What is **the simplest method** to construct such a vector taking entries
  of $P$ (*without deconstructing $P$ to $vv^T$*) where we would be sure
  that projection of this vector  onto $v$ gives a non-zero vector?

*(I suspect that the vector made from diagonal entries of $P$ has such property  but I can't prove this ... other **simple** methods should for selected entries of $P$ take into account only basic arithmetic operations like summing or multiplying these entries)*

- Is it also a method of finding such  vectors for matrices $P$ of projections onto higher dimension subspaces (for example onto plane) ?

***Edit 1***
 *Now I know that my assumption about diagonal entries was false:*   $ {\begin{bmatrix} 
  \dfrac{1}{2} & -\dfrac{1}{2}   \\
 -\dfrac{1}{2} & \dfrac{1}{2}    
  \end{bmatrix}}$

Probably there is no such a train of linear operations which can lead for randomly chosen (and from the point of view  of formula unknown) that guarantees obtaining a non-zero vector. Algorithm somewhere must have   inserted "if" statement. The last hope is in the absolute value operator (it is non linear) but I have not find a formula. It remains only to take any **non-zero** (but for this we need "if" decision) column of $P=vv^T$   (case 1 dim. subspace) and normalize it to the unit vector.

***Edit 2 ( 21 hours after)***

Even for a case of dimension  2 is hard to find a solution and to prove that solution is impossible in the general case. 
Let's say that we want to construct vector from entries of projection matrix $P$

which for $P$ generated by a vector $v=[x \ y]^T$ are $x^2, y^2, xy$

i.e.

$vv^T= \begin{bmatrix}
x^2 & xy \\
xy & y^2 
\end{bmatrix}$

what means that the wanted vector has a form in the most general case

$b=[Q_1(x^2, y^2, xy),Q_2(x^2, y^2, xy)]^T$

where $Q_1,Q_2 $ are some polynomials.
In this case we must have assured  $xQ_1+yQ_2\neq{0}$ because $v$ and $b$ should not be orthogonal.

For a limited range of possible $x,y$ values it is possible to construct such a vector. Let's assume that $x,y$ are non-negative. In this case we can construct simple vector

$b=\begin{bmatrix} x^2+1 \\ y^2+1  \end{bmatrix}$

which gives   $v^Tb = x^3+x + y^3+y > 0$ for any non-negative $x,y$ so the vectors $v$ and $b$ can't be orthogonal and it is assured non-zero projection of vector $b$ onto $v$.   Such procedure can be expressed by a single formula

$b=(i^TPi +1)i+(j^TPj +1)j$

however its usage is not universal, it is dependent on the assumed restricted values of $x,y$, (in this case it can be easily extended for any dimension).

*(I have described above procedure not to give a solution, because for restricted values of $x,y$ to non-negative numbers even the vector $b=[1,1]^T$ would be enough but to give a hint how the wanted general solution could be presented - this was, I think, unclear here for some users, maybe now it is more explicit what I expect from the solution.)*

Comment: I am not sure if this is the simplest method, but how about solving $(P - I)x = 0$ where $I$ denotes the identity matrix? The set of solutions is the space of eigenvectors to the eigenvalue $1$. Since $P$ is a projection matrix, this is its image.

Comment: @Matthias Klupsch Yes, it is not so simple like taking some entries of $P$ and compose with them the wanted vector. Is it my assumption about taking diagonal entries of $P$  true or false ? It has an  advantage that it eliminates the case of P with zeros in some columns.. I suppose (it's rather obvious) for projection matrix it is impossible to have all zeros on diagonal..

Comment: No, taking diagonal entries will not work in general. An example where this does not work is $P = \left(\begin{smallmatrix} 2 & -1 \\ 2 & -1 \end{smallmatrix}\right)$. However, you are right that nonzero projection matrices have to have a nonzero diagonal entry since their trace is the dimension of their image.

Comment: @MatthiasKlupsch Your $P$ matrix is not a projection, I suppose, because it isn't of the form $vv^T$.  .. ?

Comment: What is a projection for you? For me it's a matrix $P$ with $P^2 = I$.

Comment: @Mathhias I see, you mean $P^2=P$ ? I mean **orthogonal** projection where projected vector $a$on a unit vector $v$ is equal   $ v(v^Ta$), I've forgotten to add "orthogonal" word..

Comment: Yes, I meant $P^2 = P$. Unfortunately, I don't know much about orthogonal projections.

Comment: @Mathias I see. Problem can be considered only for numbers. ..For example my supposition about diagonal entries is equivalent to that: for  $a,b,c..$ with property $a^2+b^2+c^2+...=1$ it holds $a^3+b^3+c^3+...\neq0$ ?...

Comment: @Mathias Your example with non-orthogonal projection was  however useful because thanks to this (you have used dimension 2, I was thinking mainly about 3D) I have found counterexample to my supposition. Unfortunately diagonal entries don't work for dim 2.

Comment: What’s your objection to recovering $v$ by computing the kernel of $P-I$?

Comment: @amd Originally  I wanted to calculate not exactly $v$ but **any** vector which gives non-zero projection in a possibly the simplest way, I was thinking it is possible ( recipe something like taking diagonal entries which proved to be false), but I see there is probably no simple way.

Answer (score 1):

For one dimensional projection the solution is easy, in fact if your matrix $P$ is zero then your vector is $v=0$, now suppose that you have a non zero entries in $P$ say $a_{i,j}$ where $(P=(a_{i,j})_{i,j\leq n})$ so if you put 
$$
v=\frac{1}{\sqrt{\sum_{k=1}^n a_{k,i}^2}}(a_{1,i}, a_{2,i}, \dots , a_{j,i}, \dots a_{n,i})
$$
you can see that $v$ is a unit vector, and that $v$ answer to your question, in fact we have a 1 dimensional projection so the dimension of $Ran(P)$ is equal to one, that mean that : 
$$
Ran(P)=\mathbb{R}v
$$
where $v$ is any nonzero vector in the range of $P$, but we know that any column in a matrix is the image of the canonical basis.

Comment: Yes, it is true, however it is not the exact answer for the question because you have assumed that we know which column is non-zero, it means we are able to use logic of "if-then type. I constrained solution only to the train of typical linear operations like summation, multiplication, scalar product, transpose etc.. by your formula starting from $P$  matrix we, without checking what are non-zero columns, could generate also zero vector ( or rather not generate because it be would division by 0)

Comment: I don't understand very well what kind of method you want @Widawensen , because i think that this one is very direct and clear.

Comment: @Widawensen since $\operatorname{tr}P=\|v\|^2=1$, you only need to scan the main diagonal to find a non-zero column, but that doesn’t seem to be the sort of thing you’re looking for.

Comment: Of course you are right Hamza, maybe it is a little non-standard question because I wanted to impose some restrictions on the method and not to use "If-then" decision when constructing a wanted vector.....example.. Let[s suppose that we would want to calculate sum of diagonal entries of P, we can use **always** formula $sum=i^TPi+j^TPj+k^TPk.$ - it should be something like this formula.

Comment: @amd Amd, could you do this by a pure matrix operation not using "if-then" decision ?

Comment: @Hamza  As you see I upvoted your answer although it is not exactly what I wanted ( leads to the good result but with "if -then" decision" which I wanted to exclude from the solution)

Comment: @Widawensen Nothing comes to mind right now, unfortunately. At first, I thought of summing the rows and normalizing, but that fails if $v\perp\mathbf 1$.

Comment: @amd Even for a case of dimension  2 is hard to find a solution and to prove that solution is impossible. Let's say that we want to construct vector from entries of $P$ which for $P$ with a vector $v=[x \ y]^T$ are $x^2, y^2, xy$ what means that the wanted vector has a form in the most general case $b=[Q_1(x^2, y^2, xy),Q_2(x^2, y^2, xy)]^T$ where $Q_1,Q_2 $ are some polynomials. In this case we must have assured  $xQ_1+yQ_2\neq{0}$ because $v$ and $b$ should not be orthogonal.

Comment: @amd I've added Edit 2 to my question (starting from the comment above) maybe it could be inspiring..