# Converting from rotation matrices to axis angle at $\pi$

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, rotations

This formula converts rotation matrices to axis angle form:

$$\large \vec{r}=\frac{1}{2\sin{\theta}}[(r_{32}-r_{23})\hat{i}+(r_{13}-r_{31})\hat{j}+(r_{21}-r_{12})\hat{k}]$$

However it is undefined at $\pi$ and $-\pi$ . So is there any other formula for this special case?  Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In this case  one should directly calculate the axis of rotation represented by the unit vector $v$ from Rodrigues formula for a rotation matrix $R$

$R=I+\sin(\theta)S(v)+(1-\cos(\theta))S^2(v)$

where $S(v)$ is  a skew-symmetric matrix assigned to the vector $v$

$S(v)=\begin{bmatrix}
0 & -v_z & v_y  \\
v_z & 0 & -v_x \\
-v_y & v_x & 0
\end{bmatrix}$

One can check that   additional relation $S^2(v)=vv^T-I$ is fulfilled and taking this into account and  $\theta=\pi$ we obtain $R=I+2(vv^T-I)$ and then $vv^T=(R+I)/2$.

Having $vv^T=\begin{bmatrix}
v_x^2 &  v_y v_x& v_zv_x  \\
v_xv_y &  v_y^2& v_z v_y\\
 v_x v_z &  v_y v_z & v_z^2
\end{bmatrix}$ we can calculate $v = [ v_x \ \  v_y \ \ v_z]^T $.

Comment: Ok but what are the inputs of Vx, Vy, and Vz. ?

Comment: @AbuBakr These are precisely components of the unit vector representing the axis, you have noted it as $\vec{r}$... I as $v$, we can calculate them from listed above matrix $vv^T$

Comment: @AbuBakr If you are still unsure about  the proposed solution I recommend you  to test it  on some easy for calculations matrix,  take for example the matrix $A$  from the question  https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1836077/a-certain-unique-rotation-matrix

Comment: Thanks a lot. This works just fine, but can the equation above still calculate all the solutions if the singularity is at $\pi$

Comment: @AbuBakr I'm not sure what means your additional comment. $\pi$ case has always two solutions $v$ and $-v$ because $R(v,\pi)=R(-v,\pi)$ and these two solutions can be obtained from analyzing any **non-zero** column (or row)  of matrix $V=(R+I)/2$. Start from the entry from the main diagonal - here we have two solutions $\pm\sqrt{V_{diag}}$, then the remaining two  components of $v$ can be  obtained unambiguously.