# can't compute rotation from 3d rotation matrix just from eigenvalues and eigenvectors

Tags: eigenvalues-eigenvectors, rotations, orientation, orthogonal-matrices

Starting with a $3 \times 3$ rotation matrix $R$, I would like to know the axis and angle of rotation.

It seems like a popular topic for questions on this forum, but I can't quite find the answer to my question (see below).

I proceeded as follows but couldn't quite complete the task.

I know that $R$ has a real eigenvalue equal to $1$ and two complex eigenvalues of the form $e^{i \theta}, e^{-i \theta}$. Let $\mathbf{v}$ be an eigenvector with eigenvalue 1. Then $v$ determines the axis of rotation and the angle of rotation is $\theta$ or $-\theta$.

If we assume the right hand rule, then I believe that exactly one of these angles is correct, but which one? The answer changes as I negate my choice of eigenvector, so I'm thinking that there is another invariant of the matrix $R$ that I need to extract (besides the eigenvalues and eigenvectors).

For example, consider the rotation matrix 
$R = 
\begin{bmatrix}
0 & -1 & 0 \\
1 & 0 & 0 \\
0 & 0 & 1
\end{bmatrix}
$. One choice of eigenvector is $\mathbf{v} =
\begin{bmatrix}
0 \\
0 \\
1
\end{bmatrix}
$. Relative to this choice, I think that most will agree, the angle of rotation is definitely $90^ \circ$ and not $-90^ \circ$. I'd like to make that determination for more general rotation matrices?

Any ideas?

Comment: I can think of moving a the xyz reference frame into position for any rotation. That might do it.

Comment: I admit I was a little sloppy; $e^{i \theta}$ only determines $\theta$ up to an integer multiple of $2 \pi$. Still, $\theta$ and $-\theta$ generally differ by something else so my question is still valid.

Comment: It’s meaningless to speak of the direction of the rotation without first defining an orientation, which is what you’re doing when you choose between $\mathbf v$.and $-\mathbf v$: a clockwise rotation about some axis looks exactly the same as a counterclockwise rotation when viewed from the opposite direction. There’s nothing intrinsic to the rotation matrix that will allow you to decide on the “correct” orientation. You’ll have to use external criteria to do that. This point has come up before, although I can’t find the relevant questions at the moment.

Comment: It seems to me that the question still stands. Assuming that I've chosen an eigenvector $\mathbf{v}$, how do I decide on the angle of rotation?

Comment: You could flip a coin.

Comment: amd, either you're just being glib or you believe that it's wrong for me to expect that the angle of rotation be determined from the matrix and a choice of eigenvector. I added an example to my post to address the latter case.

Comment: You can use for axis this question and answer https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2291731/converting-from-rotation-matrices-to-axis-angle-at-pi/2293081#2293081  first for angle use $\text{tr}(R)=1+2cos\theta$.

Comment: @amd - I don't think you have to flip a coin.

Comment: @Widawensen That formula for the angle has a sign ambiguity.

Comment: The example that you’ve added underscores my point. You’ve made a choice of eigenvector that is to represent the axis of rotation in a way that’s entirely extrinsic to the matrix. Why choose that particular vector instead of $(0,0,-1)$? Having done that, you still have another choice to make: what a positive angle means relative to this vector. You’re implicitly using a version of the right-hand rule, but that, too, is a choice that is extrinsic to the matrix itself.

Comment: That said, Rodrigues’ rotation formula establishes a particular convention for the meaning of the sign of the angle relative to a choice of vector to represent the rotation axis. Choosing an angle consistent with that convention seems a reasonable way to go.

Comment: @amd Change of sign changes the direction of axis,  we have in this case $R(v,\theta)= R(-v,-\theta)$ but it is exactly the same operation, represented by the same matrix.

Comment: @Widawensen You’ve missed my point. The formula you give has exactly the direction ambiguity that the OP asks about: the matrices of rotations through $\theta$ and $-\theta$ have exactly the same trace. Moreover, if $\mathbf v$ is an eigenvector, then so is $-\mathbf v$, so you can’t extract the original orientation from the matrix, either.

Comment: @amd Having decided what sign of the angle ( $+\theta$ or  $-\theta$ ) you prefer the axis can be calculated unambiguously. See for example formula from https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2291731/converting-from-rotation-matrices-to-axis-angle-at-pi , to say more accurately both the angle and the axis are determined from the Rodrigues formula, angle from trace of symmetric part of rotation matrix, axis from skew-symetric part. Using eigenvalue 1 seems to be really not sufficient.

Comment: @Widawensen You’re making my point for me. Rodrigues’ formula produces the same matrix for $(\mathbf v, \theta)$ as for $(-\mathbf v,-\theta)$. There is nothing *intrinsic* to a rotation matrix that lets you resolve this ambiguity. Choosing a sign for the angle is an *extrinsic* decision. Once made, one can then come up with all sorts of ways to compute an axis/angle pair that’s consistent with that decision, but it is an *arbitrary* decision that is not informed by anything in the matrix itself.

Comment: @amd you are perfectly right . . .

Comment: @amd I don't understand what your issue is. Seems like the question was: if given $R$, find a $(v,\theta)$ pair that would produce $R$. It seems intuitively obvious that both $(v,\theta)$ and $(-v,-\theta)$ would produce the same $R$ so why argue about whether it's intrinsic or extrinsic? We just want to know that the answer is not $(v,-\theta)$ or $(-v,\theta)$. Given that both  $(v,\theta)$ and $(-v,-\theta)$ are valid solutions, is there a better answer than the one I gave?

Answer (score 1):

I think I figured out a solution. Let $\mathbf{v}$ be any eigenvector of the rotation matrix $R$. Let $\mathbf{w}$ be any vector independent of $\mathbf{v}$. Let $\theta$ and $-\theta$ be the arguments of the complex eigenvalues of $R$.

The angle of rotation is the argument above with the same sign as $(\mathbf{w} \times R\mathbf{w}) \cdot \mathbf{v}$.

Comment: This is a nice, simple, solution. Note that you can take for $\mathbf w$ one of the standard basis vectors (as long as it’s not the axis of rotation). Then $R\mathbf w$ is the corresponding column of $R$ and their cross product is a simple rearrangement with negation of the components of $R\mathbf w$. This lets you find the sign without having to apply the rotation or compute a cross product explicitly.

Comment: @amd This answer is not correct. $\mathbf{v}$ cannot be "any eigenvector of the rotation matrix $R$". It must be the axis of rotation, i.e. the eigenvector associated with the eigenvalue of 1. If $\mathbf{v}$ is the axis of rotation, then the solution works quite nicely per your comment. Perhaps I'm being too picky, but this is not a solution using  "just the eigenvalues and eigenvectors".

Comment: @TLDavis Good catch. $\mathbf v$ must indeed be an eigenvalue of $1$. I didn’t pay close enough attention to that.